# windows10pro 64bit モニターが勝手に復帰する

Tags: windows-10

「次の時間が経過後、ディスプレイの電源を切る」で3分に設定後、3分後にディスプレイが消灯するが何分間か経つと復帰します。15分に設定した場合は問題ありませんでした。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

これらの記事に色々まとめられています。ご質問の症状に当てはまるようなものは無さそうですが。

[Windows10がスリープから勝手に復帰する時に確認すべき項目まとめ](https://deaimobi.com/windows-sleep/)
[Windows10スリープ移行後すぐ起動する。](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/windows10%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97/5a3863f6-3f56-4dda-8e95-42434154aa20)
[Windows10が夜中に勝手にスリープ復帰する場合の解決法](https://freesoft.tvbok.com/win10/tips/sleep_released_unintentionally.html#a02-1)

記事の中にイベントログによる調査方法なども解説されているので、それで調べてみてください。
あと、OSだけでなく、BIOS(メインボード)による何かの設定があるかもしれません。